# WP Plugin to make a menu like this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, responsive-design, menu, megamenu

Anyone who know of a WordPress plugin, which can make a side scrolling mobile menu like on this website: https://www.gardena.com/

I have tried Ubermenu and Quadmenu without any succes …
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this?
(it has wordpress plugin version, too)

https://mmenujs.com/